# Rails: Highlight the last record inside a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to highlight the last entry inside a loop. But the following code assigns id="highlight" to every table row :(

```
  <% @sales.order("created_at desc").each do |sale| %>
    <tr <% if sale.created_at = Sale.last %>id="highlight"<% end%> >
      <td><%= sale.user.name %></td>
      <td><%= sale.product %></td>
  ....
```

Any ideas? Thank you guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if sale.created_at = Sale.last
```

should be

```
if sale.created_at == Sale.last.created_at
```

Alternatively, I guess the following would be better, since it eliminates an additional query `Sale.last`:

```
<% @sales.order("created_at desc").each_with_index do |sale, idx| %>
  <tr <% if idx == @sales.length - 1 %>id="highlight"<% end%> >
    <td><%= sale.user.name %></td>
    <td><%= sale.product %></td>
....
```

HTH

Comment: if sale.created_at == Sale.last.created_at did it for me. THX!

Comment: Glad I could help, although I would strongly advise against it. You should use `each_with_index` way to get last (or any) record.

Comment: The 'each_with_index' does not work, as it highlights the oldest and not the newest/latest table row.

Comment: Try with `if idx == 0`. I missed the `order("created_at desc")`.

Answer (score 2):

To get the number of rows (without an additional db query), you can use:
 @sales.length

Then use each_with_index for your loop:

```
<% @sales.order("created_at desc").each_with_index do |sale, i| %>
  <tr <% if @sales.length == i + 1 %>id="highlight"<% end%> >
    <td><%= sale.user.name %></td>
    <td><%= sale.product %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the way you are using the `=` sign.

Note that equality(`==`) is different from assignment(`=`).

What you need is the equality sign(`==`) here. so:

```
<% if sale.created_at == Sale.last %>id="highlight"<% end%>
```

as opposed to:

```
<% if sale.created_at = Sale.last %>id="highlight"<% end%>
```

which you are doing.